# DFS and replacement with for_each

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

How can I replace for loop of DFS() with for_each loop.Please let me know if there's any other efficient way to create graph or any sites teaching Graph through STL that I can basically use for competitive programming?

```
void DFS(int s)
{
  visited[s] = true;
  cout<<s<<"  \n";
  for(vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it=AdjList[s].begin();it!=AdjList[s].end();it++)
  {
    if(!visited[it->first])
    {
        //cout<<it->first<<endl;
        DFS(it->first);
        edgeTo[it->first]=s;
    }
  }
}
```

for whole code http://ideone.com/iXO9QO

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [Boost Graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html). It provides implementation of all text-book graph algorithms and more in very efficient and compact C++.

Comment: Thanks, but I think BGL is not included in simple gcc...so will be unavailable while submitting code to JUDGE,yet can be used in project making I guess... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That loop in DFS is very simple, so I doubt you need to use for_each for that.
And for your information,

```
vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it=AdjList[s].begin();
```

can just be

```
auto it=AdjList[s].begin();
```

Using auto keyword will reduce much volume from your code.

Well, personally I have implemented all major graph algorithms with STL.
Seeing your code, I say you are on the right path to competitive programming already. 
While boost offers all kinds of readymade libraries, STL is sufficient enough for one to implement graph algorithms with.